# valores de uma lista em Java

Tags: java

Galera boa noite!

Estou escrevendo um código que requer que um numero seja multiplicado por ele mesmo 200 vezes até então tudo bem, porém o que não estou conseguindo é imprimir 10 valores em uma mesma linha formando um total de 20 linhas por ex:

num = 7

1=7 2=14 3=21.........................................10=70

11=77.................................................20=140

199=1393..............................................200=1400

Segue abaixo o código que consegui até o momento...

```
package tabela;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tabela {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num , resp;

    System.out.println("Digite um número inteiro: ");    
    num = entrada.nextInt();

     for (int cont = 1; cont <=200; cont++ ){
         resp = num * cont;

        if((cont <=10)||(cont <= 200)){ 
        System.out.print( cont + "=" + resp+"\t" );
        }       

    }int cont = 0;             

    }  
 }
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta adicionando o que fez ate agora.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Se tiver uma lista, pode chamar os itens assim:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList <>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {

        System.out.println(list.get(i));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa quebrar a linha quando a sua variável `cont` for divisível por `20`. Para isso você pode utilizar o operador `Remainder` ou `Modulus` representado pelo caractere `%` que irá retornar o resto de uma divisão. Ou seja, quando você fizer a verificação `cont % 20` resultando em `0`, a quebra de linha é necessária:

```
if (cont % 20 == 0) {
  System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Substituindo no seu código:

```
package tabela;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tabela {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num, resp;

    System.out.println("Digite um número inteiro: ");
    num = entrada.nextInt();

    for (int cont = 1; cont <= 200; cont++) {
      resp = num * cont;

      System.out.print(cont + "=" + resp + "\t");

      // Quebra a linha quando o cont for divisível por 20
      if (cont % 20 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```